# how to prompt user to fire an action in Struts2

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsp, struts2, presentation

I have a 3 layer web application using Struts2, Spring and Hibernate.
I want to prompt user in a JSP page (Struts2 in presentation layer) and if ok is pressed, an action occur.

I can not find any prompt tags in Struts2.

Comment: How do you want to prompt user?

Comment: Please provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the prompt in the onclick event like this:

```
onclick="return confirm('Continue?')"
```

Otherwise you need to redirect to the correct url of the action with window.location or call form.submit() programatically

Comment: is there any way other than javascript?

Comment: No, javascript is for anything dynamic on the client side. Plus struts is ancient technology it barely has any javascript generation support like JSF does

Comment: Struts2 ancient over jsf? please. And of course there are ways to handle OP case w/o javascript.

Comment: I mean, by all means if you want to develop a modern UI in 2016 using Struts JSPs,  go ahead. But at least put your money where your mouth is and provide OP with a solution.

Comment: Who is talking about *S2 jsp-s*?, btw what do you mean by that term? So you are building *modern UI* with jsf? ;) S2 isn't pure UI framework. And it has js plugins.

Comment: So OP asks for a non-JS solution and you suggest a JS plugin that is using fake prompts as the solution? Makes sense. I never said I would use JSF, what I said was it has way better javascript generation support than Struts. Anyway this is not an opinion sharing forum, if you can't provide a solution just don't comment.

Comment: @highstakes What's a "fake prompt"?

Comment: Fake prompt = one made with javascript not the native one with the original behavior.

Comment: I see. Either are made via JavaScript, and let's face it, native browser prompts are ugly and don't have a lot of features. YMMV.